# Are there other EKM providers for SQL Server than Hashicorp's Vault and Luna EKM?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I would like to implement Extensible Key Management for SQL Server. I am reading through documentation that:

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/extensible-key-management-ekm?view=sql-server-ver16)

> The SQL Server Extensible Key Management enables third-party EKM/HSM vendors to register their modules in SQL Server.

However, I cannot find any list of all available providers. While googling I have only found Hashicorp's Vault and Thales' Luna EKM. I believe there is one in Azure but I am only using GCP.

Please if you know any other providers or even better a list, let me know.

Comment: Please don't use inline `code` markdown for names; names aren't code, they are names.

Comment: MS is unlikely to maintain such a list - they've implemented the database side of the specification and vendors implement the cryptography side. That said, try searching for "hardware security module" (also abbreviated as HSM). This will get you more vendors, but you'll have to vet each one to see if they can work as an EKM in the sense that MS means.